# Simple Php mailer missing some bits

Tags: php, mailer

I copied some PHP mailer and at some point had it working. But the thing is, I think it's missing something I want specifically, I need to make the final email output display like below:

Name: [name of sender here] 
Subject: [subject here] 
Message: [message here]

See if the format above can be done I would like to add a company input field too at some point. here's he php mailer below:

```
<?php 
//print_r($_POST);
    if(isset($_POST['_save'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];

        if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($subject) || empty($message)) {
            if (empty($name))
                $error['name'] = "Please enter your Full Name";
            if (empty($email))
                $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid Email Address";
            if (empty($subject))
                $error['subject'] = "Please Write a Subject";
            if (empty($message))
                $error['message'] = "lease write a message, inquiries or other concerns above";
        }
        else { //if not empty

            $headers="From: {$email}\r\nReply-To: {$email}"; //create headers for email
            mail('email@domain.com',$subject,$message,$headers); //mail the message;
            $success = "Thank you! You're email has been sent.";
            #done;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly; you can't just make up a new field called company like name, subject and message. You will have to put your company name in the message-part (or subject if you'd like that). Mind being more specific?

Comment: Then add a company name to your form and put it in whereever you need it to be. What have you actually tried to do?

Comment: I got such quick replies. Thanks. I know I need to add $company = $_POST['company']; on the first if there. and also on the if empty checking there. but let's make it simple let's forget about the adding company name for now. I just want the final sent email to display on the body of the email like this.
Name: [name of sender here] <br/>
Subject: [subject here] <br/>
Message: [message here]<br/>

Comment: sorry if I'm not making much sense there. I just don't know how to say it. :)

Comment: @OptimusCrime: Yes, SMTP explicitly allows for custom headers (with an X- prefix), or maybe wolverene just wants to stick this in the subject / body, or even the display name (ref RFC 2822)

Comment: You might want to read up on email header injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, change

```
mail('email@domain.com',$subject,$message,$headers);
```

to

```
$content="Name: ".$name."<br>Subject: ".$subject."<br>Message: ".$message;
mail('email@domain.com',$subject,$content,$headers);
```

As for your second question, as Jan states, add a company name field to your form and do exactly the same as with the name/subject/message variables.

Comment: Yes, I will try that one right now. Thanks. I'll get back to you if it  goes well.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the company input any time you want by just adjusting the following example:

```
   $email_message = '
        Name: ' . $name . '<br />
        Subject: ' . $subject . '<br />
        Message: ' . $message . '
        ';


    $headers="From: {$email}\r\nReply-To: {$email}"; //create headers for email
    $semi_rand = md5(time());  
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";  

    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .  
                "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";  

    $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n" .  
                    "Your email application may not support this format.\n\n" . 
                    "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .  
                    "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n" .  
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n" . 
                    $email_message;

    $email = mail('email@domain.com',$subject,$email_message,$headers); //mail the message;
    if($email){
        $success = "Thank you! You're email has been sent.";
    }
```

I adjusted your headers a bit with the example above because not every email client will accept your email. Tell me if this is what you need.

Comment: Alex you have a point there about not every email client will accept my email. Your code solves it for a different thing I'm testing too. Hmmm. But for the my targeted email client, the other answer works perfect. Can I check or pick two great answers here? :)

Comment: I'm glad my answer is helpful, If the answer posted by @samn is what you actually needed then you should flag his as the correct answer and adjust the "This answer is useful" arrow to make the number go up from 0 to 1

Comment: Yes but to click the up arrow to make the number go up from 0 to 1 i would need to have a reputation of 15. I have only 10 for now. I will get back to it when I have achieved a 15 rep. Thanks.